# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type ObservableCollection because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display a search result API in a ListView.

This is the model which I want to display in the ListView:

```cs
    public class Video
    {
        [Key]
        public int VideoId { get; set; }
        public string Exercice { get; set; }
        public string Titre { get; set; }
        public int Sexe{ get; set; }
        public int Categorie { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUpload { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        [ForeignKey("Machine")]
        public int Machine_Qr { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the get method:

```cs
   public async Task<ObservableCollection<Video>> search(string qr)
        {
            string url = Base_url + "machines/" +qr;
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);

                    var result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Video>>(result);
                    return json;
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;

        }
```

the result json value:

> [
> {
> "videoId": 7,
> "exercice": "string",
> "titre": "string",
> "sexe": 0,
> "categorie": 0,
> "level": 0,
> "filePath": "string",
> "dateUpload": "2022-07-07T13:13:39.725",
> "machine_Qr": 7895,
> "machine": null
> }
> ]

This is the View.cs

```cs
  public partial class SearchResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        IMachineService _rest = DependencyService.Get<IMachineService>();

        public SearchResult(string value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            qr.Text = value;
            GetVideos();
        }
        public async void GetVideos()
        {
           string value = qr.Text;

            var result = await _rest.search(value);
            if (result != null)
            {
                Videos = result;
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Video> videos;
        public ObservableCollection<Video> Videos
        {
            get { return videos; }
            set
            {
                videos = value;

            }
        }
```

but I got an exception while debugging this line in the service

```cs
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

and this is the detailed exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[App5.Models.Video]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'type', line 1, position 8.

Comment: there are dozens of existing questions about this identical error.  Further, the error message itself if very clear: "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type"

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+deserialize+the+current+JSON+object+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @jason I tried to change the JSON to JSON array but nothing changed

Comment: Please add to question the value of `result` that you are now trying to deserialize. Also, I recommend doing a "hardcoded" test. That is, explicitly set `result` from a literal string, e.g. `var result = "[1, 2, 3]";`.  (Replace those numbers with appropriate values for your situation - whatever `Video` expects. Maybe these are strings with video names?)

Comment: please post a sample of the json you are using

Comment: @jason check the question

Comment: you are getting the **exact** same error message as before?  And you are **positive** that the json returned by your server is now an array?

Comment: @Jason yes it's the same exception and the jason returned is an array

Answer (score 1):

Do this as a test:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Video> search(string qr)
{
    try
    {
        var result = "[ { \"videoId\": 7, \"exercice\": \"string\", \"titre\": \"string\","
            + " \"sexe\": 0, \"categorie\": 0, \"level\": 0, \"filePath\": \"string\","
            + " \"dateUpload\": \"2022-07-07T13:13:39.725\", \"machine_Qr\": 7895, \"machine\": null } ]";
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Video>>(result);
        return json;
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Put breakpoint on both return statements. To make sure this really is the code that is giving the error. Which breakpoint does it hit now? Does it print the same exception message?